# Is it possible to refer to a whole column in Google Spreadsheets using R1C1 format?

Tags: google-sheets

In Google Spreadsheets I often use A1 notation to refer to a whole column:

```
A1:A
```

For reasons I explain below, I'd like to use R1C1 format, to refer to a whole column, something like:

```
R1C1:C1
```

It's not possible to use A1:A in Excel, so as R1C1 notation originated from Excel, it seems unlikely that its possible to do this in R1C1 notation.  If it is, it'd make my life easier.

Background: I have a spreadsheet visits, which pulls information from another spreadsheet data, which has a dynamically changing format.

To get around this, I use a formula to generate an address in a cell, based on the current layout of data.  I can then reference this address cell in other formulae using indirect.  And it's much easier to generate an address using R1C1 than A1.

Comment: "As it's not possible to use A1:A in excel" - do you mean "As it's not possible to use R1C1 in excel" ?

Comment: No, I meant that the range A1:A only works in Google Docs - with excel you have to specify both row and column for the end of a range.

Comment: I can't read R1C1 notation without wondering about a R2D2 one.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Short answer

Yes, it's possible to refer a whole column using R1C1 notation: Use `INDIRECT("C1",FALSE)`

## Explanation

Google Sheets doesn't include a feature to change the reference notation from A1 to R1C1 but the last could be used with the [INDIRECT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377?hl=en) built-in function.

### Example

In a sheet having 1000 rows, the following formula will return 1000

```
=ROWS(INDIRECT("C1",FALSE))
```

Comment: Genius! Thanks :)

Now almost 4 years have passed since I asked the question, now I just need to remember what I was doing when I asked it!

Answer (score 10):

A1 notation is supported now.  To center column A:

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A1:A").setHorizontalAlignment("center");
```

Comment: A1 notation has always been supported, but my questions asks whether it's possible to to use R1C1 notation to refer to a whole column in Google Spreadsheets.

Answer (score 2):

No, but you can work around it, by knowing which row is the last row with data in a column, using the `COUNTA` function.

`INDIRECT("A1:A")` could be written something like `INDIRECT("R1C1:R" & COUNTA(R1C1:R1000C1) & "C1")`

You need to determine a sensible 'max rows' value. I've used 1000 in the example, so this formula should work in a spreadsheet with up to 1000 rows.

Look up `COUNTA` in the [Google Spreadsheets function list](https://support.google.com/docs/bin/static.py?hl=en&topic=25273&page=table.cs).

Comment: Now it's possible (see my [answer](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/98166/88163). Maybe this was introduced on the new Google Sheets.

Comment: Ah, that's great!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible:

A1 Notation: A:A is an absolute reference to Column A whereas
R1C1 Notation with square brackets is a relative reference, so you count from the current cell.

Example: If current cell is D1, then as column A is 3 columns to the left you can refer to it as C[-3]:C[-3].

Answer (score -1):

The acceptable format varies depending on the method being used. In [this one](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation), for example, the description allows for R1C1 notation, but it's unclear (to me at least) whether the input or output is R1C1 notation.

I recommend adopting the use of `getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)` instead ([Official doc here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow-column-numrows-numcolumns)). Based on the given details of your intended use, this would suit your purposes quite well. I frequently use a variable for the 'row' parameter to retrieve a whole range of values in a loop. e.g., `getRange(row, 2, 1, 7)` where row = 3 would return the range `C2:C8`. Then, simply increment 'row' to return the next range D2:D8.

Comment: You are not answering the question of how to refer to the whole column, instead of a specified number of routes in that column. Using getRange repeatedly in a loop is not recommended unless necessary, it leads to poor performance and quota issues.

Comment: As for what you found unclear in getRange method: its output is a range object, not a string, so there is no question of notation for it. The notation is specified for input, which is a string.

Answer (score -2):

YES...refer to whole column as C:C... rather than range as C15:C25 ...

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. As this is a "late answer" (the question is old and already has multiple answers), please ensure that this answer adds something not already said in previous answers. It might be a fuller explanation if that is not already available, and explain why this answer is correct. Related help article [answer]

Comment: Actually this is using A1 notation, as I mentioned in the first code snippet: but i asking how to solve this using r1c1 notation.