# How do I make row():row() a range?

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to count the number of non-empty cells in a range that depends on the row number. I've tried `counta(row()+3:row()+4)` which always returns 1 as does `counta(row():row())` (where I would have expected a circular dependency). `counta(12:12)` works fine, as does `count(13:14)`.

How do I make a range that is dependent on `row()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot construct a range specification like that. You'll want the `=INDIRECT` function ([documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377?vid=1-635798006255742032-2068237842)), in order to translate a row number into a range.

You must also include the *column* in your range. If your range spans columns `A` to `C`, from row `1` to `3`,  the range should be `A1:C3`. This can be constructed from a string: `"A" & 1 & ":C" & 3`. Replacing the row numbers with `row()` from your question, we get `"A" & row()+3 & ":C" & row()+4`, which leads us to the final formula:

```
=COUNTA(INDIRECT("A" & row()+3 & ":C" & row()+4))
```

Comment: Thanks. Works, except that it doesn't need to include the column range. It can ignore the specific columns as well with `COUNTA(Indirect((row()+3)&":"&(row()+4)))`.

Answer (score 0):

The [other answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/85234/88163) mentions that the reference should include the column but this isn't this way nowadays, as a reference of the form `1:1` is valid in the current version (2019) of Google Sheets.

Anyway, the other answer is right regarding to use a formula to build a reference we should use INDIRECT.

```
=COUNTA(INDIRECT(ROW() + 3 &":"& ROW() + 4))
```

Related

- [Is it possible to refer to a whole column in Google Spreadsheets using R1C1 format?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/33410/88163)